# In Java, why does consuming a URL give a SSLHandshakeException with one port but not with another port with the same certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-io

In the following Java code, I consume two different URLs with the same hostname but different port numbers. They both serve exactly the same certificate (I downloaded and diffed them). But the one with port `6443` gives an `SSLHandshakeException`, while the one with port `443` succeeds. Why would Java object to the certificate for the `6443` URL?

```
package httpsrequesttest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpsRequestTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] urls = new String[]{
      "https://geoeventsample1.esri.com:6443",
      "https://geoeventsample1.esri.com"
    };
    for (String url : urls) {
      try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        System.out.printf("%s\n\tSuccess\n\tFirst line: %s\n", url, in.readLine());
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n\tFailure\n\tError message: %s\n", url, ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The output:

```
https://geoeventsample1.esri.com:6443
    Failure
    Error message: SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
https://geoeventsample1.esri.com
    Success
    First line: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: As far as I see, it depends on certificate:
https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/326/17/can-a-single-ssl-server-certificate-cover-multiple-ports-per-domain-name

Comment: Because it isn't the same certificate.